# terraform changes in json file won't get updated

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, policy

I have a AWS SNS module that create a sns and its policy

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic" {
  name                                  = var.name
  display_name                          = var.name
  content_based_deduplication           = var.sns_content_based_deduplication
  fifo_topic                            = var.fifo_topic
  firehose_success_feedback_sample_rate = var.firehose_success_rate
  http_success_feedback_sample_rate     = var.http_success_rate
  lambda_success_feedback_sample_rate   = var.lambda_success_rate
  sqs_success_feedback_sample_rate      = var.sqs_success_rate
}
resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "topic_policy" {
  arn = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
  policy = templatefile("./sns_topic_policy.json", {})
  depends_on = [aws_sns_topic.topic]
}
```

And a json file in the same directory `sns_topic_policy.json`

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "__default_policy_ID",
"Statement": [
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
        "AWS:SourceOwner": "*"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I did apply and everything. Now I want to update the policy in json file

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "__default_policy_ID",
"Statement": [
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
        "AWS:SourceOwner": "*"
        }
    },
{
    "Sid": "Example SNS topic policy",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "SNS:Publish",
    "Resource": *,
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
        "aws:SourceAccount": *
        },
        "ArnLike": {
        "aws:SourceArn": "*"
        }
    }
]
}
```

But when I ran `plan` it says no changes to make. Anyone ran into the same problem and what is your solution for this? Assuming keep using json file for policy (In order to keep the `main.tf` a little more clean)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `aws_account_id`, `sns_arn` and `source_arn` in the json? They are undefined currently. Does your code   even compile?

Comment: You tried to deploy? And check if changes?

Comment: Please ignored the contents in the json. I was trying to make it look simpler which ended up doesnt make sense. Sorry.
But yes, It was deployed, then when I tried to modify the policy in json - sns policy did not get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this AWS [link](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to generate your policy. I use this tools for my policies in Terraform and I've never had an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can add a var to the templatefile function, and reference it in the policy. Then, increment the value each time you edit the policy. This will trigger the update.

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "topic_policy" {
  arn = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
  policy = templatefile("./sns_topic_policy.json", { version = 1 })
  depends_on = [aws_sns_topic.topic]
}
```

**sns_topic_policy.json**

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "SnsPolicy${version}"
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Even better would be passing the version as a variable:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "topic_policy" {
  arn = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
  policy = templatefile("./sns_topic_policy.json", { version = var.policy_version })
  depends_on = [aws_sns_topic.topic]
}
```